# Register event handler for Ajax (Bootstrap-Tree) loaded checkboxes

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When my page is first loaded, I register the event for all my checkboxes:

```
$(":checkbox").change(function () {
var $this = $(this);
if ($this.is(':checked')) { }...
}
```

The HTML template I am modifying uses bootstrap-tree to load new content. [Demo](http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/index.php?theme=metronic&page=index.html) (UI Features -> Tree View -> Data Sources [The right tree]).

I want to register event handlers for the checkboxes loaded in the new branches, so I want to catch the event when the ajax content is loaded. I have searched related questions in SO and tried the following methods:

```
//$(document).on('click', '.ajax', function () {
//$(document).ready(function() {
//$('a.ajax').live('click', function() {
//$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
```

But none of them work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DOMSubtreeModified` and `unbind`

```
$("#divId").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    alert("dom tree changed");
    $(":checkbox").unbind('change').bind('change', function () {
        // your binding code
    });
});
```